# Pi Camera V2 not working

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspicam, picamera

When I type the command `vcgencmd get_camera`, I get the following output: `supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0`

And when I type the command `libcamera-still -o test.jpg`, I get the image generated from the camera. How is this possible?

Comment: found this old post https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4697

Comment: What do you get from `libcamera-hello --list-cameras`. All of the `raspicam` and `vcgencmd` stuff for cameras has been deprecated now in favour of the `libcamera-*` stuff. See https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html